# how to export/import websites,stores,store-views?

Tags: database, importexport, core-config-data, websites

I have a Magento install with 58 websites, and i need to recreate them in a new installation. Is there any way to export the database table which handle this?, and then import it in the new DB?. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 3 tables needs to be exported/imported to recreate websites/stores/store-views in a different Magento install:

- core_website
- core_store_group
- core_store